# Why is finding parent scale important in playing modes?

Tags: chord-theory, modes

I am reading Nicholas Carter's Music Theory: From Beginner to Expert.
I am at the part where he explains altered Dominant chords provide easy access to parent melodic minor scale because if b9, #9, #11, b13 are added to Dominant chords it becomes an altered scale, which is the seventh mode of melodic minor scale. And it is easy for seventh mode to find parent scale.

While reading this, I just wondered, why is finding parent scale important?

Comment: Theory is, after all, descriptions or practices. Apparently this book fails to explain what practice it is describing, if it is left unclear to the reader, how and why something is done. :/ Or are there some practical exercises the reader should do?

Answer (score 1):

I would question the premise... A 7-note scale generates 7 different modes. It's definitely useful to explore all of them for the purpose of exercise, education and maybe inspiration. However, while you're playing a specific scale over a specific chord, you don't necessarily need to worry about the other modes.

It might be helpful though to notice similarities between consecutive scales. E.g. if the harmony is Dm7 G7 Cmaj7, and you use D dorian, G mixolydian and C ionian, it certainly helps to realize the three scales use the same notes.

Scales sharing notes look the same on the instrument, so the fingering patterns might be shared. However, the same licks and phrases may not necessarily work, because different notes have different functions over different chords or in a different context.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I see no value in the "parent scale" concept, but in the case of the altered scale, or other rotations of the melodic minor scale, I see one particular value for the keyboard.

> ...an altered scale, which is the seventh mode of melodic minor scale.

If we use that origin for an altered scale and start with a "tonic" or root of `C`, we get this scale...

`C D♭ E♭ F♭ G♭ A♭ B♭ C`

The next part is a little complicated, but I'll try to be brief. The major and minor scale and diatonic "Church" modes can be viewed as being built from two concatenated tetrachords. If you divide those scale into two halves, both will encompass a perfect fourth (`P4`). With a `C` tonic, the two halves will run `C F` and `G C`. That makes for a kind of common link between a great many scales and modes in tonal music.

When you divide an altered scale into halves you get `C D♭ E♭ F♭` and `G♭ A♭ B♭ C` which encompass a diminished fourth (`d4`) - enharmonically a major third - and an augmented fourth (`A4`). From the perspective of playing diatonic scales and modes on keyboard, that altered scale looks strange and feel awkward to play.

However, if you've practiced all the minor scales (as you should), and someone points out a `C` altered scale is the seventh rotation of a `D♭` (or enharmonically a `C♯`) ascending melodic minor scale, it becomes much easier to deal with, because you can rely on your familiarity with melodic minor.

So, for example, you see an `F♯7alt` chord symbol, with some practice you can quickly think "up a half step to `G`, play a melodic minor scale."

To me that is the value of identifying a "parent scale". Linking a melodic minor scale to an altered dominant chord. It is really just an expedient for *fingering* an altered scale.

Otherwise, finding parent scales for the diatonic modes has never helped me. In a diatonic context the parent scale concept seems to be some end run to avoid learning key signatures and basic harmony. When a musicians reads, for example, `Em7 A7 D6`, they should be able to see the passage is `ii V I` in `D` major, the key signature is two sharps, and the tones are `F♯` and `C♯`.

Answer (score 0):

It's important for a player who primarily runs scales or relies on knowing specific scale-chord associations. It also can be helpful in understanding relationships with surrounding musical material.

Answer (score 0):

Most, if not all of us, learn scales before modes - so they're (hopefully) deeply ingrained in our playing, and used as a backbone for a lot of it. Some of us then go on to learn modes in their own right (as in the intervals making up Dorian, Mixolydian, etc.) or - referring back to the parent scales, which we already know. Personally, I find the second method making more sense, as I don't need to re-learn, from a different slant, something I already know.

So, not convinced that the premise of this question holds water for everyone. Using ♯9, ♭9, etc, just means (to me) using those notes when necessary, and changing them in accordance to the chord concerned.

But, knowing what the parent scale of any mode is is important (to me at least), as I can then refer to it while playing, just emphasising the 'new' root note of the mode in question. E.g. D Dorian - D note from C scale, F from F Lydian (again C scale parent). And so on.

Different views of the same thing, whichever one prefers.